# NavigationView swiftui not full screen

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

how to remove top space from navigation view 
Note1: with out navigation it shows full screen 
Note2: if i use this(`.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`) inside image it shows full screen but image not fill properly please check both image view.

Here is my code:

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    Image("splash_screen")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill)
                       // .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    //.frame(height: geometry.size.height)
                }

            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .background(Color .red)

    }
```

[image]

Comment: think about, how it should looks like on devices with different width to height ratio? that is the first what you have to know ...

Answer (score 0):

Works with this. Add property `.scaledToFill()` to Imageview.

```
 ZStack {
     Image("LandingBg")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                          // .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                       //.frame(height: geometry.size.height)
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it shows full screen but cropped image

Comment: I thought you are looking for full screen fill. Can you please provide screenshot that how it should look like?

Comment: Can you please try by removing resizable() property?

Comment: it make more small